# How to format a block of variables in PHP?

Tags: php, coding-style

I just want to know which way of formatting I should prefer if I have to declare a block of variables.

I saw a alignment-style several times:

```
$foo    = 'foo';
$bar    = 'bar';
$foobar = 'foobar';
$baz    = 'baz';
```

and a assignment-style:

```
$foo = 'foo';
$bar = 'bar';
$foobar = 'foobar';
$baz = 'baz';
```

Is there a standardized way or a official guideline for this? I already searched for this in [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) but it seems that these standards do not handle this question.

And if there is no official answer how do other languages handle this and why do they prefer the way they do it?

Comment: its a matter of coding taste, style, and choice..for clearance they both look damn fine to me..imho

Comment: I do not think there is something like assignment-style coding .The first is preferable as It looks good and more readable nothing extra you got with any of both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to you. Aligned assignments and comments tend to look quite beautiful, but they tend to be more "maintenance-heavy". For example, a tool-assisted refactoring change of a variable name can throw off your entire indentation.

Unless you maintain that carefully, you can end up with code ten years later like:

```
$foobiedoobie     = 'foo';
$barquax    = 'bar';
$foob = 'foobar';
$boob        = 'baz';
```

... as though someone did a drive-by shooting all over your careful formatting. My former workplace was like that -- it's hard to keep these styles looking good in a team setting with a really large codebase, and especially in a version control setting where you might come across these "drive-by shootings" and have to face the difficult decision of leaving it as it is (to avoid committing more code changes than necessary), or fix it (and risk annoying other people on your team).

So these can look really beautiful in the beginning, but unless you maintain their beauty, they can get really ugly over the years.

Meanwhile, take a style like this:

```
$foo = 'foo';
$bar = 'bar';
$foobar = 'foobar';
$baz = 'baz';
```

... and it's not quite as pretty -- or at least some may think so. But it'll tend to look pretty much the same no matter how the variables are renamed with refactoring/text find & replace tools.

It's arguably not as pretty, but it's pretty much guaranteed to age well, whereas the former one tends to age well only if you actively maintain it (or don't make any changes to the code).

Comment: Thanks for the long comment. It described by doubts very well. My problem is, that I think I have to restructure my program in a cleaner way, e.g. with an additional method to reduce the count of variables.

And I want also not commit any line because I edited just one word, therefore I personally prefer the way without indenting the value.

Comment: I ended up settling on that latter style as well later on. I started with the aligned style but I went through that kind of team experience. But everyone's mileage may vary. In my case, I worked with some slobs who would just use like VisualAssist, rename identifiers all over potentially multiple files, and would commit the code without fixing the indentation. If you work with a more conscientious team that has a proper coding standard specifying how to format, probably it won't be as big of a deal. That said, that second style for me is the safe one -- it's a bit homely but it doesn't have...

Comment: ... that risk of degrading so much. And it's also easy to figure out where to put comments for the variables, e.g. (can just put them right above the variable without breaking that alignment). It's a very "plain" style, and you often can't too go too far wrong with those.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, i prefer the first style, it's more clear and readable, but it's a personal opinion

My advice is to give a suffix for your variables to know very quickly their type:

```
$vari = 5;              # i => integer
$vara = array("hello"); # a => array
$vars = "hello";        # s => string
// ...
```

It's simple, but can help a lot when you coding thousands of lines :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on context.
For example (from Zend Framework):

```
    $this->_mode             = $this->_detectMode();
    $this->_homeDirectory    = $this->_detectHomeDirectory();
    $this->_storageDirectory = $this->_detectStorageDirectory();
    $this->_configFile       = $this->_detectConfigFile();
```

But if you have comments:

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $_storageDirectory = null;
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $_configFile = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

PSR doesn't say a word about it, so generally there's no unified convention. It's a matter of personal preferences or company coding standards.

"Alignment-style", as you called it, maybe looks better, but not every IDE can format code like this (using built-in refactoring features), therefore it may be irritating for some people, as IDE format feature would "broke" the convention when you format whole file with a shortcut.